Can not record Robo Script in Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
I click the button "Record Robo script" in the Assistant window in Android Studio. Then a build and run is made on my real device (Pixel 8 Pro). And few seconds later the ballon appears in Android Studio: "Processes com...***** are not found. Aborting session."
What I do wrong? Is there a workaround?

This might be an issue that affects not only Robo script Recorder. What happens if you run the debugger for your app with exactly the same setup?
